# Display Modal ViewController in PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, uipageviewcontroller

I have a master page in my application that is based on PageViewController.  On that master page I have a side bar that provides options to the user.  One of the options is to display "About" information regarding the application.  When the user click the About button in the side bar, I want to display my AboutViewController as modal.  It appears all my linking up is correct however when I click the About menu option in the side bar, the whole screen simply goes black (which is the background color or my AboutViewController) and none of the content in my AboutViewController is visible.

Here is the code for my PageViewController.  The highlighted code is the code that displays the modal view controller.

[image: Code for Master Page View Controller]

Here is a screen show of About View Controller Scene that I am trying to display.

[image: About Info scene]

Where is a screen shot of what the app looks like before I click the About button:
[image: Before Click About]

This is how a click the About button:
[image: Clicking About button]

This is what I get after I click the about button:
[image]

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: Per the comment provided I updated my code as follows and I am still having the same problem.

```
            gobj_sideBar.showSideBar(false)
            iobj_AboutViewController = AboutViewController()
            iobj_AboutViewController?.iobj_CloseAboutInfoDelegate = self
            iobj_AboutViewController!.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
            // Cover Vertical is necessary for CurrentContext
            iobj_AboutViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
            // Display on top of    current UIView
            self.presentViewController(iobj_AboutViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also - I don;t believe a blank page is being displayed as in the code for my About View Controller I do have the following line of code which turns off the status bar and the status bar is not visible on the scene displayed when I click the about button.

```
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {

    return true;
}
```

OK So I switched to using Modal Segues as suggest and that mostly works.  The only challenge I have now is that I want the About View Controller to display as a small popup type view but instead it is taking up the full screen as seen below:

[image]

These are the properties I have set for my About view controller.  Any idea how I should change it so the view comes up as a popup type window where the background is grayed out but the About view does not take up the entire screen?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not experienced enough to tell what's wrong but I am spotting some mistakes in your code :

- modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle are to be set on the presented view controller not on the presenting.
- You instantiate an AboutViewController, save a reference to it and set self as its delegate but in the call to presentViewController(...) you instantiate another AboutViewController

Also consider that the black is not the background color of your About scene but instead the color of a blank screen.

If I were you, I'd use a segue for that about scene as well, it's less error prone. And instead of delegation to dismiss the About view controller, try an unwind segue.

Comment: OK - I am not familiar with Modal Segues.  Might you be able to provide some more details on that?

Comment: Never mind about the Modal Segue.  Figured it out.  Kind of got it working now.  Please see update to question. :)

Comment: I simple hack would be to select "Over Fullscreen" in Presentation and make the root view of that about controller transparent or almost transparent and move your text and button in a subview with a black background.

Comment: I used Julien's suggestion above and it works OK.  Definitely a hack.  There should be a better way to do this but it works.